# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process at SharePoint 2010 C# code

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am creating custom timer job service in SharePoint 2010 using asp.net 3.5 and c#.In this service, business logic is that i have to create zip file containing list of applications as excel report for each client.for this, i am using Ionic.zip third party dll and ZipFile class for creating zip file and storing this zip file on hard disk having some path.here scenario is that my code contains two foreach loops, upper for list of clients and inner for list of applications.each client may have no. of applications.I am adding these applications to zip file, storing it on hard disk and attaching this file to mail for sending to clients, but my problem is that I am trying to delete zip file before gone to next client, so that there should not be any files on  hard disk, but I am getting error as "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".also I have tried to attach output stream for excel report as mail attachment but I am getting zero bytes in attachment. how should i overcome this error.
I am giving simple code below

```
foreach(list of clients)////may have no. of clients
{
  string zipFileDownloadPath = String.Empty;
  foreach(list of applications)//may have no. of applications
  {
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
    Stream excelReport = resp.GetResponseStream();
    zipFile.AddEntry(appName, excelReport);
  }
  zipFileDownloadPath = clientFolder + @"\" + client["client_name"] + "_" + reportDate + ".zip";
  zipFile.Save(zipFileDownloadPath);
  mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(zipFileDownloadPath));
  smtp.Send(mail);//mail have body, subject etc.
  //here I am deleting files
  if (Directory.Exists(clientFolder))
  {
    Directory.Delete(clientFolder, true);//here I am getting error
  }
}
```

I the above code I have also tried so save zipfile to output stream so that there should not be any need for storing files on hard disk and attach this stream to mail attachment, but problem is that, i am getting proper bytes in output stream but when mail is sent, i am getting zero byes in attachment.
//here is code for attaching output stream to mail

```
foreach(list of clients)////may have no. of clients
{

  foreach(list of applications)//may have no. of applications
  {
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
    Stream excelReport = resp.GetResponseStream();
    zipFile.AddEntry(appName, excelReport);
  }
  Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
  zipFile.Save(outputStream);
  mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(outputStream,"ZipFileName" MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);));
  smtp.Send(mail);//mail have body, subject etc.
}
```

Comment: You should actually delete the file rather than whole folder. If 2 people are working, it will create two different files. In that case, it won't be able to delete the folder

Comment: I have tried to delete file also, but still am getting same error

Comment: kindly request you to suggest me proper solution how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the position of the stream to it's begiining before sending it to the attachement:

```
outputStream .Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Also before deleting your file make sure you dispose the zipFile object:

```
zipFile.Dispose()
```

Or alternately (better) wrap it in a using statement.

Also unless I am missing something if you are using streams, why do you need to save the files to the harddrive? just use the streams, something along the lines of:

```
var ms = new new MemoryStream();
zipFile.Save(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms,"ZipFileName" MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip));
zipFile.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks Luis.I have solved my problem. the only problem was that I was not seeking the position of output stream to beginning before attachment. so now I have modified my code as you have suggested and I am getting precise result.once again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to Luis.Luis has solved my problem.

Hi Everyone Finally I have solved my problem. problem was that I was saving the zip file on output stream so stream was reading exact bytes and reaching at it's last position and I was attaching same stream to attachment that's why i was getting zero bytes in mail attachment.so solution for this is that seek the position of output stream to begin after saving to zip file and before attaching to it to mail. please refer following code for reference.

```
Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
zipFile.Save(outputStream);
outputStream .Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(outputStream,"ZipFileName" MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);));
```